# Python: Get file path from a text file

Tags: python, path, extract

Let say there is a sample text file in Linux

```
[SampleText.txt]

1234 = 1234

abcd = 1234

efgh = /home/user/targetfile1.txt

ijkl = /home/user/targetfile2.txt
```

How I can get the specific path (/home/user/targetfile1.txt & /home/user/targetfile2.txt) out from the SampleText.txt and place it in a variable?

Comment: Are you asking how to read a file in Python?  Please ask a more specific question, since this appears to be simply `open("sampleText.txt","r").read()`.  What part of reading a file is confusing?  Or are you asking about finding the file name in a line of data?  If so, what are the **actual** formatting rules for the line of data?  It would help us if you could post the code you've written so far, so we know what part confuses you.

Comment: No, that no what I means

Comment: I am able to read but how can I filter to get the filepath in the text file

Comment: "that no what I means".  Okay.  Please **update** the question to say what you actually  mean.  What part of reading a file is confusing to you?  Please try to be very **specific** about your problem.  We can't guess.  Please do not add comments.  Please **update** the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggested approach is to parse the file as a general configuration file, and store things that look like assignments. If you have other weird stuff going on in your file, this may not work, but I think it will work here.

```
myvars = {}

# iterate through all the lines
for line in open('SampleText.txt').readlines():
    # skip this line if it doesn't look like an assignment
    if not '=' in line: continue

    # split it into left and right pieces
    left, right = line.split('=', 1)

    # keep it around in a dictionary
    myvars[left.strip()] = right.strip()

# now you can query it to get stuff:
myvars['efgh']   # returns /home/user/targetfile1.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the ConfigParser module:

http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html

It parses files that look like this. Not knowing your exact situation, I can't be sure.